# Where can I submit a Cordova App to the Windows 10 App store?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-2015

I have built my first app in Ionic/Cordova and have made a build for Windows 10 in Visual Studio.

Where is the website/page to upload this to the Windows 10 app store?
Do I need to register as a Windows developer somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Got it now https://dev.windows.com/en-us
There is a Submit Your App link

Costs £12 for individual membership or £55 for company membership